# How do I access the Magento REST API with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, rest, magento, oauth

I want to start working with Magento's REST API, but I can't seem to get it working.

To start with I need to get access tokens, here's what I'm trying:

```
require 'oauth'

@consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new("4200100753b2c8b03bde1f5b062c5a80", "c06abdcb734c85dfd7bb115c6a67ae4d", {:site=>"http://178.62.173.99/"})
@request_token = @consumer.get_request_token

# => oauth-0.4.7/lib/oauth/consumer.rb:216:in `token_request': 404 Not Found (OAuth::Unauthorized)
```

But I keep getting a `404` error.

What should I try next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a Ruby module I've written to create an access token for the Magento REST API:

```
module Token
  def create_consumer
    OAuth::Consumer.new(
      CONSUMER_KEY,
      CONSUMER_SECRET,
      :request_token_path => '/oauth/initiate',
      :authorize_path=>'/admin/oauth_authorize',
      :access_token_path=>'/oauth/token',
      :site => URL
    )
  end

  def request_token(args = {})
    args[:consumer].get_request_token(:oauth_callback => URL)
  end

  def get_authorize_url(args = {})
    args[:request_token].authorize_url(:oauth_callback => URL)
  end

  def authorize_application(args = {})
    m = Mechanize.new

    m.get(args[:authorize_url]) do |login_page|
      auth_page = login_page.form_with(:action => "#{URL}/index.php/admin/oauth_authorize/index/") do |form|
        form.elements[1].value = ADMIN_USERNAME
        form.elements[2].value = ADMIN_PASSWORD
      end.submit

      authorize_form = auth_page.forms[0]

      @callback_page = authorize_form.submit
    end

    @callback_page.uri.to_s
  end

  def extract_oauth_verifier(args = {})
    callback_page = "#{args[:callback_page]}".gsub!("#{URL}/?", '')

    callback_page_query_string = CGI::parse(callback_page)

    callback_page_query_string['oauth_verifier'][0]
  end

  def get_access_token(args = {})
    args[:request_token].get_access_token(:oauth_verifier => args[:oauth_verifier])
  end

  def save_tokens_to_json(args = {})
    auth = {}

    auth[:time] = Time.now
    auth[:token] = args[:access_token].token
    auth[:secret] = args[:access_token].secret

    File.open("#{args[:path]}#{args[:filename]}.json", 'w') {|f| f.write(auth.to_json)}

    auth
  end

  def get_new_access_tokens
    new_consumer = self.create_consumer
    new_request_token = self.request_token(consumer: new_consumer)
    new_authorize_url = self.get_authorize_url(request_token: new_request_token)
    authorize_new_application = self.authorize_application(authorize_url: new_authorize_url)
    extract_new_oauth_verifier = self.extract_oauth_verifier(callback_page: authorize_new_application)
    new_access_token = self.get_access_token(request_token: new_request_token, oauth_verifier: extract_new_oauth_verifier)
    save_tokens_to_json(filename: 'magento_oauth_access_tokens', path: '/', access_token: new_access_token)

    return 'Successfully obtained new access tokens.'
  end
end
```

Run `#get_new_access_tokens` to get an access token.

Don't forget to define the following variable:

- CONSUMER_KEY
- CONSUMER_SECRET
- URL
- ADMIN_USERNAME
- ADMIN_PASSWORD

Answer (score 1):

Check out [mage on rails](https://github.com/yattias/mage-rest-on-rails). It should work right out of the box. Check out [this page](http:///github.com/yattias/mage-rest-on-rails/blob/master/app/controllers/mage_controller.rb) for annotated ruby code showcasing the oauth flow